# bash script, replacing directory paths

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file which contains directory paths like:

```
drivers/i2c_v1/init.c
drivers/spi_v3/init.c
drivers/usb_v5/init.c
drivers/pci_v9/init.c
```

I need to find out whether the particular line is a directory path or not (a directory path always starts with "drivers/") and how to remove a part of a path segment that contains the string "_v".

According to the example above the desired result is:

```
drivers/i2c/init.c
drivers/spi/init.c
drivers/usb/init.c
drivers/pci/init.c
```

Comment: Are the paths saved in file space seperated or newline seperated ?

Comment: What does this have to do with the `linux-kernel` or `drivers`?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to make changes on lines starting with "drivers", you can do

```
sed -i "/^drivers/s/_v[0-9]*//g" yourfile
```

That will remove all instances of "_v" followed by any number of digits.

If "drivers" is not at the start of the line, remove the caret (^).

Answer (score 0):

To remove _v from the paths:

`sed -i "s/_v//g" fileName`
**Note:** This will edit the file inplace.

Comment: This will replace all _v in file right.
I need to replace _v* contents to nothing in patch's
those are starts with drivers/